# Proper usage of Assuming statement

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, assumptions

I want to evaluate a command under an assumption, and thought `Assuming` was the right way to go. Suppose we want to calculate a Matrix rank. Following the second example in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html), I tried

```
Assuming[a == 1 && b == 1,
 MatrixRank[({
    {1, a},
    {b, 1}
   })]
 ]
```

But this outputs 2, not 1. So what is going wrong?

Comment: `Assumptions` is not an option of `MatrixRank[]`, so that's not going to work.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! Is there some command to define global assumptions then? (In this case, one could define `a:=1` before, but what if the assumption is something more sophisticated like `a>b>1`?)

Comment: That's `$Assumptions`, but it's still not going to work here (it's mostly for calculus functions like `Sum[]` and `Integrate[]`). In the meantime, look at `Reduce[Thread[Diagonal[First[LUDecomposition[{{1, a}, {b, 1}}]]] != 0], {a, b}]`.

Comment: From the documentation, "Assuming **affects** the default assumptions for all **functions that have an Assumptions option**" (emphasis added).

Comment: +1 I agree with OP that the syntax of `Assuming` purports to do more than it actually does. Less experienced users will naturally assume that it affects everything within it. More experienced users could be expected to do `Block[{$Assumptions=...},...]` or so. I usually do not use `Assuming` at all and stick to `Assumptions->...`, then at least I am alerted by the editor when a command does not take that option.

Comment: @user, that sounds like useful feedback to send to Support, which I warmly encourage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the comments and the documentation, [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) evaluates an expression with new assumptions appended to [`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), so that the specified assumptions are included in the defaults used by functions such as [`Refine`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refine.html), [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), and [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html).

[`MatrixRank`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixRank.html) will ignore [`$Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html), but [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) will not.

Consequently, you could [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) first and evaluate `MatrixRank` later, obtaining `1` as you expected,  like this:

```
Assuming[
    And[
        a == 1,
        b == 1
    ],
    MatrixRank@FullSimplify[
        {
            {1, a},
            {b, 1}
        }
    ]
]
```

[image]